# Is there a git hook for `git add`?

Tags: git, githooks

I been researching but haven't had any exact luck on:

1. knowing where exactly to look for these answers
2. what to search on google beyond variations of "Is there a git hook for `git add`?"

So, here I am, wondering if there is a way I can have a pre-add, during-add, or post-add hook to add a linter. My work currently has one for post-commit which is pretty annoying because I have to amend each time something changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `pre-commit` hook which isn't during `add` but during `commit`. It is however run before other hooks during the commit process. It even runs before editing the commit message.

If it's for yourself you could also just create an alias and get in the habit of using that instead of plain add.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

First, to add a pre-add command, define the alias `ladd` (linter+add):

`git alias.ladd '! your-linter-command; git add'`.

Then you can use as  the `add` command: `git ladd`

PS: [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book is the place to look for git information.